# How to rearrange the angle of existing polygons

Tags: vertices

I'm trying to think of the easiest way to connect the opposite angles of the quads, as shown in the figure below, are there any existing solutions?
I've found a way with inset modifier + collapse, but after that there's an old grid that's hard to isolate

[image: Example]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a little trick, which also helps to make diagonal grids for modeling knurls, nettings, trellises, gratings, etc.

[image]

- <kbd>W</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> Subdivide your mesh
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> edge menu, Un-subivide  it.

Done.

It's odd that the operations aren't inverses of one another ... Un-subdivide it *again*, and you're back to where you started. As Mr. Zak point out in his comment, the iterations should be set to 1. Odd numbers of iterations yield diagonal divisons.

Comment: Note that there should be 1 iteration in operator settings (or Decimate modifier if it's used instead) for unsubdividing or it will give straight grid

Comment: @MrZak cheers. ,, I should have put that in. ... and I didn't know you could use the Decimate modifier to do it.

Comment: Dear Robin, your solution is not obvious, and very elegant, thank you. I found another one with (1. Inset vertices, 2. Collapse, 3. Limited dissolve in Vertex mode) but your looks more angle independent and better.